# Google Chrome can't display a .eps file

Tags: html, google-chrome, eps

I want to add the "Download on the App Store"-badge. The file I downloaded is a .eps which displays correctly in Safari but not in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://linktoitunes">
        <img class="appstore" alt="Download on the App Store" src="../appstore-badge.eps" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: EPS is not a standard web image format and browsers does not support it by default.

Comment: EPS stands for Encapsulated PostScript and it's a fairly complex file format targeted at graphic designers. Whoever is interested in downloading it will do it to manipulate it with a graphic design tool or to embed it in documents. There's actually little interest in displaying it in a browser.

Comment: EPS is neither an image nor a file format, its a program written in PostScript, a programming language. A the other commenters have indicated, this is not a web standard, so web browsers will generally only handle it. If they do i will be by passing it to a PostScript interpreter to render to an image format (such as PNG) and then displaying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the image to a format more commonly used on the WWW.

Use SVG if you want to continue to use a vector format. Otherwise JPEG for photo-like images and PNG for images where precise reproduction of the original is important.